# MS SQL Server: Load All Data vs Aggregate with +1 round trip

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, razor, azure-sql-database

I love to get your opinion on this problem.

I need to show the list of order records for the range of particular date/time. Then summarise it with **# of Order** compare with the **"last"** order. **"Last"** can mean either ***last month*** OR ***last year***

Since I am going to show the list of order record, I am thinking to get the record from ***last month*** OR ***last year*** with one hit (ie. **together with the records of current date/time range**)

**OR**, alternatively, I can:

1. Get the record of current date/time range, THEN
2. Get the total number of order (using aggregate) for ***last month*** OR ***last year***

The alternative means there is **2 round trips** to database (but less data to return). Or should I stick with my current method (loading all records including those from ***last month*** OR ***last year***).

> **NOTE:** The website and the SQL server is hosted in Microsoft Azure Cloud. But we might switch to AWS in the future.

Thanks

---

Input example (some fields are omitted including time for simplicity)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Warehouse Id | Order Id | Product Id | Quantity | Order Date |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|            1 |       10 |          1 |       10 | 2016-09-25 |
|            1 |        9 |          5 |        5 | 2016-09-24 |
|            1 |        8 |          4 |        8 | 2016-09-23 |
|            1 |        7 |          6 |        2 | 2016-09-23 |
|            1 |        6 |          8 |        1 | 2016-09-23 |
|            1 |        5 |          1 |        2 | 2016-09-22 |
|            1 |        4 |          1 |        2 | 2016-09-21 |
|            1 |        3 |          5 |       10 | 2016-09-21 |
|            1 |        2 |          5 |       15 | 2016-08-12 |
|            1 |        1 |          5 |        5 | 2016-08-10 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The desire OUTPUT:

```
Input:
   WarehouseId: 1
   StartDate: 2016-09-01   End Date: 2016-09-30)
   Comparison type: Last Month (ie. StartDate: 2016-08-01   EndDate: 2016-08-31)

Output:
Warehouse: xxx
-------------------------------------------------
| Order Id | Product Id | Quantity | Order Date |
-------------------------------------------------
|       10 |          1 |       10 | 2016-09-25 |
|        9 |          5 |        5 | 2016-09-24 |
|        8 |          4 |        8 | 2016-09-23 |
|        7 |          6 |        2 | 2016-09-23 |
|        6 |          8 |        1 | 2016-09-23 |
|        5 |          1 |        2 | 2016-09-22 |
|        4 |          1 |        2 | 2016-09-21 |
|        3 |          5 |       10 | 2016-09-21 |
-------------------------------------------------
Total Order: 40 (increase 100% from last month)
```

So, what I am doing now is to get ALL records from 2016-08-01 to 2016-09-30. That way I can avoid 2 round trips.

Alternatively, I can do the following:

```
1. Get record from 2016-09-01 to 2016-09-30
   var rec = (from rec in tblOrders
              where (rec.WarehouseId == whsId) && (rec.OrderDate >= startDate) && (rec.OrderDate <= endDate)
              select rec).ToList();
2. Then do the SUM of total order from 2016-08-01 to 2016-08-31 for comparison purposes
   var recSum = (from rec in ef.tblOrders
                 where (rec.WarehouseId == whsId) && (rec.OrderDate >= cStartDate) && (rec.OrderDate <= cEndDate)
                 group rec by rec.WarehouseId into grec
                 select new
                 {
                     TotalQty = grec.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results, so there is some attempt to enable other people to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Provide your input table and expected output...

Comment: I have modified my question and provide a simple example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*
             sum(case when datetime is "last month" or "last year" then 1 else 0 end) over () as last_num_orders
      from orders o
     ) o
where o.datetime between @date1 and @date2;
```

I am very unclear what "last" means in this context.  However, you can do what you want with window functions, which is the preferred option `0`.

Comment: I have modified my question and provide a simple example. Thanks :)